# Why does my eventDrop only working for weekly and daily view? For the monthly view, eventDrop works when under inspect only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am truly confused with what is happening but here is my code that I believe, is related to the problem. As mentioned, ONLY the eventDrop is not working for the monthly view. While in weekly and daily view, eventDrop works. And if I open the web under inspect, the eventDrop works fine. Would love to know the solutions! Thanks in advance.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testing.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css" />
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" /> -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
      function toggleMenu(){
            let toggle=document.querySelector('.toggle');
            let navigation=document.querySelector('.navigation');
            let main=document.querySelector('.main');
            toggle.classList.toggle('active');
            navigation.classList.toggle('active');
            main.classList.toggle('active');
        }
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    displayEventTime: false,
    editable:true,
    header:{
     left:'prev,next today',
     center:'title',
     right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    events: 'load.php',
    selectable:true,
    selectHelper:true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay)
    {
     var title = prompt("Enter Event Title");
     if(title)
     {
      var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
      var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
      $.ajax({
       url:"insert.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:{title:title, start:start, end:end},
       success:function()
       {
        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        alert(title+" added successfully.");
       }
      })
     }
    },
    editable:true,
    eventResize:function(event)
    {
     var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var title = event.title;
     var id = event.id;
     $.ajax({
      url:"update.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
      success:function(){
       calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
       alert(title+" updated.");
      }
     })
    },

    eventDrop:function(event)
    {
     var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var title = event.title;
     var id = event.id;
     $.ajax({
      url:"update.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
      success:function()
      {
       calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
       alert(title+" updated.");
      }
     });
    },

    eventClick:function(event)
    {
     if(alert("event name : "+event.title+"\nstart date : "+event.start+"\nend date : "+event.end))
     {
      var id = event.id;
      $.ajax({
       url:"display.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:{id:id},

       success:function()
       {
        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        //alert("event name : "+event.title+"\nstart date : "+event.start+"\nend date : "+event.end);
        alert("Event Removed");
       }
      })
      }
    },

   });
  });
```

Comment: How exactly are you dragging/dropping the event? Bear in mind that the month view has no concept of times, so dragging/dropping won't do anything useful unless you drag between different days, because it cannot tell what different time of day you might want to drop it on. It's not precisely clear what problem you're experiencing because there's no known bug about eventDrop in general.

Comment: I believe it's related to the bootstrap added? Im not sure which one overrides the function but it certainly doesn't work on my browser. Whereas other js works

Comment: Here's a demo using the code you've supplied so far (plus some hard-coded events I added for the purpose of demonstration)....it seems to work fine as far as the dragging and dropping is concerned: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/qBpGLab . Can you add anything to that which makes it not work any more? Your current example doesn't contain any bootstrap JS (I uncommented the bootstrap CSS you had in there, but it still worked after that too) so it's difficult to see if that's related or not. We need a [mre] of the issue before we can really help you. Thanks.